# clojure macro variable trouble with map

Tags: clojure

I'm having trouble getting a clojure defmacro to do what I want.  I've reduced my actual code down to the following snippet.

This creates something *close* to what I want.  I am trying to conditionally insert either (first p#) or (second p#) depending on a parameter passed into the macro.

```
(defmacro mmz1 [t]
  `(map (fn [p#] (let [t1# (first p#)
                      t2# ~(if t `(first p#) `(second p#))]
                  (* t1# t2#)))
        [ [1 2] [3 4] ]))

(macroexpand-1 '(mmz1 false))
```

shows

```
(map
  (fn [p__18341__auto__]
    (let [t1__18342__auto__ (first p__18341__auto__)
          t2__18343__auto__ (second p__18340__auto__)]
      (* t1__18342__auto__ t2__18343__auto__)))
  [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

But, note that the variable in this form (second p_*18340*_auto_*) does not match the anonymous function argument p*_18341_*auto*_.  So, executing the code results in an error since that second var is not defined.  How can I get these vars to match?  This is what I would like to accomplish.

For testing purposes, this code *accomplishes* what I want, but I *don't* want the (if) form in the resulting macro code that sets t2#.  A macro should allow me to do this--shouldn't it?

```
(defmacro mmz0 [t]
  `(map (fn [p#] (let [t1# (first p#)
                      t2# (if ~t (first p#) (second p#))]
                  (* t1# t2#)))
        [ [1 2] [3 4] ]))

(macroexpand-1 '(mmz0 false))
```

shows

```
(map
  (fn [p__18387__auto__]
    (let [t1__18388__auto__ (first p__18387__auto__)
          t2__18389__auto__ (if false
                              (first p__18387__auto__)
                              (second p__18387__auto__))]
      (* t1__18388__auto__ t2__18389__auto__)))
  [[1 2] [3 4]])
```

and the output of the code is the expected:

```
(mmz0 false) -> (2 12)
```

Comment: If you want the background behind this issue, I explained it (somewhat) in this query on the Overtone forums.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/overtone/CScDTtzteRk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions

```
(defmacro mmz1 [t]
  `(map (fn [p#] (let [t1# (first p#)
                       t2# (~(if t 'first 'second) p#)]
                   (* t1# t2#)))
        [ [1 2] [3 4] ]))
```

**Update**. More general solution

```
(defmacro mmz1 [t]
  (let [trg-fn (if t 
                 `(fn [p#] (first p#)) 
                 `(fn [p#] (second p#)))]
    `(map (fn [p#] (let [t1# (first p#)
                         t2# (~trg-fn p#)]
                   (* t1# t2#)))
        [ [1 2] [3 4] ])))
```

You can replace `(fn [p#]...)` in `if` branches with more complex functions.

**Update2.** Simpler solution that uses predefined function formal parameter `p`

```
(defmacro mmz1 [t]
  (let [p `p#]
   `(map (fn [~p] (let [t1# (first ~p)
                        t2# ~(if t `(first ~p) `(second ~p))]
                    (* t1# t2#)))
         [ [1 2] [3 4] ])))
```

Comment: You've answered the question as stated, since that works.  But, I'm not sure it fixes the full case that I'm interested in.  That has more text than just 'first vs 'second.  You can see that in the highlighted lines here:
https://gist.github.com/4506057#file-stringed-clj-L78-L83

I'll think on it & see if I can use your solution somehow...

Comment: Thanks again, that looks promising!

Comment: @RogerAllen I've added simpler solution.

Comment: Cool.  I think the 2nd solution will work best for my situation.  The code seems to be working.  Giving you the checkmark--thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be stated that this has no need to be a macro at all.

The function equivalent is more readable and more composable, so I recommend you use that.

Comment: The code in this question is for discussion purposes only.  It was derived from a much larger macro.